# calculating <col> width in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Has anyone found a reliable way to calculate width of a `<col>` element in chrome?

I am writing a jquery plugin where i need to calculate the widths of table columns, and using `<col>` is the most reliable way to both get and set those widths. The only problem is that I cant read them in chrome.

Here is a fiddle where it is not impossible to find out the width of the 2nd column in chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/N3yeF/4/

**My Challenge:**
Find the width of the 2nd column in chrome without having to append another row to the table.

*edit*: The crux is probably this:

> Elements with 'display' set to 'table-column' or 'table-column-group' are not rendered (exactly as if they had 'display: none'), but they are useful, because they may have attributes which induce a certain style for the columns they represent.

(from http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html)

Comment: FYI your fiddle is missing the slash on the closing tbody

Comment: I don't see the problem, it returns 95. Inspecting it in chrome shows that the width of the element is also 95, and that is correct.

Comment: My Chrome returns 0 and inspecting it also returns 0.

Comment: @ohgodwhy: my script says that column 2 width is 95px for you, and you are running chrome? what OS and what version of chrome do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the principle that a table-cell with no padding, no margin, and no border, has the same width as the column.

Now all we have to do is add a dummy table row to the end of the table.

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col></col>
        <col id='col2'></col>
        <col></col>
        <col></col>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr><th colspan='4'>This table has 4 colums. How do I get the <col> widths?</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><th colspan='2'>colspan 2</th><th colspan='2'>colspan 2</th></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='3'>colspan 3</td><td>colspan 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>colspan 1</td><td colspan='3'>colspan 3</td></tr>
    <tr><th>colspan 1</th><th colspan='2'>colspan 2</th><th>colspan 1</th></tr>
    <tr class="notseen nopad">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

Then Style it

```
tr.notseen {
    display: none;
}
tr.nopad > td {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Then, in your jQuery, just make the row is visible before you count its width.  (If the `<td>` has `none` as its display value when you take its width, you'll always end up with the value 0.)

```
var str_ = '';
$('table > tbody > tr:last-child').removeClass('notseen');
$('table > tbody > tr:last-child > td').each(function(i) {
    $col = $('table > colgroup > col').eq(i);
    $td  = $(this);
    col_width_ = $col.width();
    td_width_ = $td.width();
    // alert message can be used in FireFox to verify that values match
    alert('col: ' + col_width_ + ' ::: td: ' + td_width_);
    str_ = str_ + 'col'+i+': ' + td_width_ + 'px; ';
});
$('table > tbody > tr:last-child').addClass('notseen');
alert(str_); // alert the width of each column in table
```

If you can't add the dummy-row in your HTML markup for whatever reason, then there is always the alternative of adding it dynamically in your jQuery script.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't what you want, but here is a fiddle that calculates the column width:

http://jsfiddle.net/JVHUV/1/

As far as I can tell, `<col>` elements have no size since they are not actually rendered elements.  To get the size of a column, you need to measure actual `<td>` or `<th>` elements in your table.

Comment: i want that if you can figure out how to that generically for any table, without looking at the table ;)

Comment: in firefox and IE, `<col>` elements have size. You can also set their size which in turn sets the size of all the tds/ths under them.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `width` by adding a class to the `<col>`.

- Create a class *(use `display:block;` since `<col>` uses `display: table-column;`)*:

  ```
  .col{ display:block; width:100%; }
  ```
- Apply class to `<col id="col2">`:

  ```
  $('#col2').addClass('col').width();
  ```
- Set local variable to the `width`:

  ```
  var px = 0;
  px = $('#col2').addClass('col').width();
  ```
- Remove class from `<col id="col2">`

  ```
  $('#col2').removeClass('col');
  ```

You can then set the `<col>` width by doing the following:

```
    if(!isNaN(parseInt(px)))
        $('#col2').css('width', parseInt(px) + 'px');
```

---

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dcRn7/2/

Example:

```
function getSize(){
    var px = 0;
    px = $('#col2').addClass('col').width();
    $('#col2').removeClass('col');
    $('#result').text(px);
}

function setSize(px){
    if(!isNaN(parseInt(px)))
        $('#col2').css('width', parseInt(px) + 'px');   
}
```

Comment: it turns that that it actually **does not work**. It works when all the columns are of the same width, but doesnt work when they are of different widths: http://jsfiddle.net/dcRn7/3/

Comment: @mkoryak but since the `#realCol2` uses `display:table-cell;` wouldn't you have to change the `display` to get the width (similiar to `#col2`?

Comment: No, you can get a width of a td using .width() - but you agree that in the example column 2 width is not 100px ?

Comment: @mkoryak yes, I agree. I'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure its possible, but would be cool if there was some generic workaround so I could stop doing this: http://programmingdrunk.com/floatThead/examples/row-groups.htm